# Angular- Can a Observable works like a property?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Im trying to do a counter for a cartshop and i did a method returns an observable (the items number of my cartshop). A property get the value of that method in this way

.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {


  public num_item:number= this.NumItemsCart();

  NumItemsCart():Observable<number>{
    let cadena_items = '';
    let array_temp = [];
    let num_items=0;
    
    cadena_items = localStorage.getItem('ecmm_list_shopcart');

    array_temp= cadena_items.split(',')
    
    num_items= array_temp.length -1

    return of(num_items)
  }
}
```

html code

```
 <div *ngIf="num_item > 0" class="counter_items_cart">{{num_item}}</div>
```

But I got this advice error 'Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'number'  in

```
public num_item:number= this.NumItemsCart();'
```

Comment: Absolutely no need for an observable here, just return the number itself.

Comment: Why use an observable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use async pipe in template to unwrap your Observable to use it like a property.

```
      <div *ngIf="(num_item | async) as noOfItems" class="counter_items_cart">{{noOfItems}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `NumItemsCart()` return of type `Observable<number>` which is incomatiable with the type of `num_item`.

Needs to fix.

1. Change the type of `num_item` as `Observable<number>`

```
public num_item:Observable<number> = this.NumItemsCart();
```

2. Use `async` pipe to subscribes to an Observable ([Angular AsycPipe Doc](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe))

```
<div *ngIf="(num_item|async) > 0" class="counter_items_cart">{{num_item|async}}</div>
```

please refer the stackblitz code ref - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uopppd.